# Same SE for all regression coefficients

Tags: r, regression, standard-error, linear

I am using R to run a linear regression with interaction terms on a small data set(~40 observations, 5 explanatory variables).
My explanatory variables are coded in a way that they can take values -1,0 or 1.
There are different conditions(combinations of input variables) that are more common than others. (f.e. the case [v1=0,v2=0,v3=0,v4=0,v5=0] has 7, the case [-1,-1,1,1,-1] has only one occurrence in the data)

After inspecting the standard errors of the regression summary, I noticed that all the SE's are roughly the same. 
For example:

Variable 1           0.13716
Variable 2           0.13943
Variable 3           0.14018
...

This is the first time that I encountered such similar SE's. I assume it may be related to the low numbers of observations and possible values for each variable. So i might not actually be that unexpected.

But are there any general interpretations for such cases? I was especially asked whether or not it isn't strange for the SE's to be similar if the number of occurrences of conditions differ.

Answer (score 2):

With linear regression, the covariance matrix for the estimated effects is used to extract the standard errors. This has a very simple formula:

$ \text{Cov}(\hat \beta) = \hat \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1} $

We have $\hat \sigma^2$ as the scalar estimated residual variance and $X^TX$ is covariance of the predictors multiplied by $n$, the number of samples. We compute the standard errors for each coefficient by simply taking the square root of the diagonal of $\text{Cov}(\hat \beta)$.

How does this relate to your question? Well, if the standard errors of all the regression parameters is very similar, this implies that the entries of the diagonal of $\text{Cov}(\hat \beta)$ are all very close, which is the same as the diagonals of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ being similar values. Why might this happen? One scenario in which this might happen (but not the only one!) is if all the columns of $X$ are very similarly distributed, both in terms of variance of each column *and* the covariance with other columns.

At this point, I'm merely speculating about what your data *might* be, but given that all the variables take on the same values (-1, 0, 1), it seems quite likely that the "similarly distributed predictors" hypothesis is true.